# Magento 1.8.1 payone extension 3.5.5 cc status_mapping issue

Tags: magento-1.8

I hope you can help me.

After upgrading the payone extension from 3.1.8 to the newest 3.5.5 and checking the correctness of payone configuration with its menu 'export configuration' I detect that the creditcard  is not listed under the status mapping group though the mapping for it is set. But the credicard data itself is exported anyway under the clearingtypes. I reinstalled the extension, some times, but allways the same effect. There is also no log entry.
The creditcard is the clearing type I have ordered by payone, the other, which are listed under status_mapping not.
Here is the part of the .xml export.

```
  <status_mapping>  !!! no creditcard listet under status mapping!!!
    <vor/>
    <cod/>
    <elv/>
    <rec/>
    <sb/>
    <wlt/>
  </status_mapping>
  <payment_creditcard>
    <min_validity_period></min_validity_period>
  </payment_creditcard>
</global>
<clearingtypes>
  <cc>
    <title><![CDATA[Kreditkarte]]></title>
    <id>3</id>
```

best regards
Christian

Answer (score 0):

I marked that as a bug internally. However, I don't think this is a classic question for Stackoverflow. Feel free to add an issue at https://github.com/PAYONE-GmbH/magento-1 the next time something like this arises :)

I'll check whether I can pin down the issue and will get back to you.

Best,

Florian

Technical Partner Manager @Payone